# iPhone - delayed notifications on home Wi-Fi

Tags: iphone, ios, network, wifi, notifications

I'm close to losing my mind with this stupid issue. I've been trying to fix it for like 6 months now. So, push notifications from **all apps** are delayed or don't arrive at all. They all arrive only after like 30 minutes, or when I wake and unlock the phone. This only happens on my home Wi-Fi network, works fine on data and my friend's Wi-Fi. Here's a list of things that I've already tried to do:

- Restored my iPhone to factory settings through iTunes and DFU mode (without restoring a backup)
- Changed phones, I'm using an iPhone 11 right now, same issue
- Called my ISP and asked them to replace my router, which they did (it's been also factory reset)
- Forwarded the ports for Apple's push notification servers
- Disabled firewall in router
- Searched numerous internet threads and tried the potential solutions listed in them
- A couple of other minor things that I forgot

This issue is very specific and uncommon, writing this here is probably my last resort before I move on to drastic measures, such as changing ISP's or switching to Android, but I guess I believe in miracles. So, does anybody have any idea what could be causing this weird
problem?

Comment: Do you run your phone in low-power mode full-time?

Comment: I did on my iPhone 8 because of the worn-down battery, but now the phone is on full power all the time. Background refreshing is also turned on both Wi-Fi and Data.

Comment: so I understand you know that it's ok with Android phones. You have tried two iphones. But is there a possibility to check this issue for another iphone which is not yours?

Comment: @Andra I guess I kind of did. Today, I took my old iPhone 8 and reinstalled iOS with iTunes. Then I've created a new Apple ID on it and signed in. I've connected to my Wi-Fi and downloaded Twitter and started testing the DM push notifications. A fully clean iPhone, with factory settings, still had the same problem. There's only one common thing between the two phones - same Wi-Fi network. That's why I even created a new Apple ID. Called my ISP - not their fault, contact Apple. Contacted Apple - not their fault, contact ISP.

Comment: delaying happens also when you are using phone and wifi connection is active? not that the phone is loosing connection?

Comment: @Andra The iPhone has connection 24/7, I've tested it with an app called "Ping". Also, I've found a workaround - putting my iPhone's local IP address in DMZ section on my router fixes it. It's still a workaround, because apparently it isn't very safe and secure and I shouldn't be doing this just because my phone doesn't work properly.